# Looping over the value inside property which is present inside the struct

Tags: c#, .net, class, c#-4.0, struct

I have created a struct which have some properties such as

```
public struct DeviceDetailModel
{
  public static readonly DeviceDetailModel DT851P = new DeviceDetailModel("851P","v1","v2");
  public static readonly DeviceDetailModel DT852P = new DeviceDetailModel("852P","v3","v4");
  public static readonly DeviceDetailModel DT83P = new DeviceDetailModel("853P","v5","v6");
  public static readonly DeviceDetailModel DT854P = new DeviceDetailModel("854P");


 public string DeviceName { get; private set; }
 public string Value1 { get; private set; }
 public string Value2 { get; private set; }

 private DeviceDetailModel(string deviceName,string value1,string value2)
 {
  DeviceName = deviceName;
  Value1 = value1;
  Value2 = value2;
 }
}
```

now if i want to get a detail of single item its easy i just had to do `DeviceDetailModel.DT854P`

but the issue I would be getting a value on runtime using which I had to identify which struct property I had to return

eg = my runtime value is `853P`
I want to loop over my struct to identify where in `DeviceName` matched to this value `853P` and which should return `DeviceDetailModel.DT83P`

I was able to loop over the properties of the struct but wasn't able to get value

Editing: Based on my run time value, i need to iterate over `DeviceName`'s value and if the value matches it should return associated property

Comment: I'm not 100% percent sure if I understand the question correctly, but would maybe using a dictionary instead of your struct solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please rephrase the last 5 lines? They aren't understandable at all.

Comment: @RolandDeschain i have multiple properties in struct so key value pair wont work here for me

Comment: @Sheradil i tried to rephrase it

Comment: But the way you describe it you could just use the `DeviceName` as key and the corresponding class instance as value, or I'm I missing something here? Then there wouldn't be a need to loop at all, just directly access the dictionary item by the `DeviceName`

Comment: What would you return if the string is "Banana"? it's a struct so it can't be null...

Comment: if you simply want to iterate over something at runtime. I see no reason why you shouldn't simply create a class that has all the options as properties, using reflection to retrieve the values at runtime. Reflection might have performance issues, but since you have just 4 or 5 properties, it won't be a major hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one fairly simple option:

```
public struct DeviceDetailModel
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, DeviceDetailModel> models = new Dictionary<string, DeviceDetailModel>
    {
        {"851P", new DeviceDetailModel("851P")},
        {"852P", new DeviceDetailModel("852P")},
        {"853P", new DeviceDetailModel("853P")},
        {"854P", new DeviceDetailModel("854P")},
    };

    public static DeviceDetailModel DT851P get => models["851P"];
    public static DeviceDetailModel DT852P get => models["852P"];
    public static DeviceDetailModel DT83P get => models["853P"];
    public static  DeviceDetailModel DT854P get => models["854P"];

    private DeviceDetailModel(string deviceName)
    {
        DeviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public string DeviceName {get;private set;}

    public DeviceDetailModel? FindByDeviceName(string deviceName)
    {
        return models.TryGetValue(deviceName, out var value) ? value : (DeviceDetailModel)null;
    }
}
```

Note that the return value of `FindByDeviceName` is a `Nullable<DeviceDetailModel>` so in case you're looking for a string that's not found you wont get an exception, but `null`.

Comment: Well, that was pretty much the point I tried to make above...